# Black screenshot is saved when rendering on textureview using Crosswalk for Android

Tags: android, cordova, screenshot, crosswalk-project

I am working on an Android SDK development and It was working fine until it is was integrated with an app which is developed in the hybrid environment called `crosswalk web runtime`. SDK works fine with this app except when it captures a screenshot, it captures a black screenshot of an app. Screenshot capturing in done by SDK and it is written in `Native Android`. Upon research on the internet, I found that `crosswalk web runtime` uses **TextureView** which is a root cause of this issue.

Any help would be very appreciated. Thanks in advance.